# Don’t understand lazy regex

Tags: python, regex, lazy-evaluation

Say we have a string `1abcd1efg1hjk1lmn1` and want to find stuff between `1`-s. What we do is

```
re.findall('1.*?1','1abcd1efg1hjk1lmn1')
```

and get two results

```
['1abcd1', '1hjk1']
```

ok I get that. But if we do

```
re.findall('1.*?1hj','1abcd1efg1hjk1lmn1')
```

why does it grab TWO intervals between `1`s instead of one?  Why do we get `['1abcd1efg1hj']` instead of `['1efg1hj']`? Isn’t this what laziness is supposed to do?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vD6xF7/2 Click on `regex debugger` to see what actually happens

Comment: The regex engine parses the string from left to right and gives always the leftmost result whatever the quantifier you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex always tries to match the input  string from left to right. Consider your  `'1.*?1hj'` regex. `1` in your regex matches the first one and the following `.*?` matches all the characters upto the `1hj` sub-string non-greedily. So that you got `['1abcd1efg1hj']` instead of `['1efg1hj']`

To get `['1efg1hj']` as output, you need use a negated class as `1[^1]*1hj`

```
>>> s = "1abcd1efg1hjk1lmn1"
>>> re.findall(r'1.*?1hj', s)
['1abcd1efg1hj']
>>> re.findall(r'1[^1]*1hj', s)
['1efg1hj']
```

Comment: Yes, a negated class is the way to go in this case. But imagine that your "separator" is multi-char, for example "123" instead of "1". How would you tackle the problem in that case?
You cannot use `[^123]` because you still want the single chars to match, unless they appear together.

Answer (score 0):

```
['1abcd1efg1hj']
```

You get this because this satisfies your regex. `1.*?1hj` essentially means start from `1` then move lazily till you find `1` followed by `hj`. The `1` in between if followed by `ef` so that will not match but `.` will consume all. You don't get `['1efg1hj']` because that string has already been consumed by the first match.Use lookahead to see that both satisfy the conditions. See demo.

A lookahead does not consume string so you get both the match,

https://regex101.com/r/aQ3zJ3/5